# Syntax on converting a C# Class to an F# Class with additional constructor and methods

Tags: class, constructor, f#

I'm a newbie to F# Classes. I think this is obvious, but I'm afraid I'm brain dead. How does this C# code convert to an F# class?

C# code:

```
public class MyStroke : System.Windows.Ink.Stroke
    {
        public static Guid strokeGUID = new Guid("e3b886cc-7d89-42e9-9336-dbb38f108ab2");

        public static int DiagramId = 100;

        public MyStroke(StylusPointCollection stylusPointCollection, PenEnum penName, DrawingAttributes drawingAttributes)
            : base(stylusPointCollection, drawingAttributes)
        {
            var id = DiagramId;

            if (penName == PenEnum.InkPen)
                id = (int)penName;

            AddPropertyData(strokeGUID, id);
        }

        public static void StartNewDiagram()
        {
            System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref DiagramId);
        }

        public static StrokeCollection Label(Stroke stroke, PenEnum penName, DrawingAttributes drawingAttributes)
        {
            StrokeCollection sc = new System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection();

            if (!(stroke is MyStroke ms))
                ms = new MyStroke(stroke.StylusPoints, penName, drawingAttributes);

            sc.Add(ms);
            return sc;
        }

    }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: F# doesn't allow public static field, only properties is supported. Is fields required or they can be replaced with properties?

Comment: @JLOPD Properties are fine -- this is all in an effort to interop between C# and F#. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a bit tricky, but something like this should do it:

```ml
open System
open System.Windows.Ink

type MyStroke(stylusPointCollection, penName : PenEnum, drawingAttributes) as this =
    inherit Stroke(stylusPointCollection, drawingAttributes)

    let strokeGUID = Guid("e3b886cc-7d89-42e9-9336-dbb38f108ab2")

    static let mutable diagramId = 100

    do
        let id =
            if penName = PenEnum.InkPen then
                (int) penName
            else diagramId
        this.AddPropertyData(strokeGUID, id);

    static member StartNewDiagram() =
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(&diagramId)

    static member Label(stroke : Stroke, penName, drawingAttributes) =
        let ms =
            match stroke with
                | :? MyStroke as ms -> ms
                | _ -> MyStroke(stroke.StylusPoints, penName, drawingAttributes)
        seq { ms :> Stroke }
            |> StrokeCollection
```

Caveat: I haven't tried to run this code, so I don't know if it actually works.

Comment: Great! So functions are added as "members" and the do statement preforms the actions within the constructor.  Got it. Thanks.  (I was trying to put the If statement outside of the do :()